# Returning a string in C

Tags: c, dynamic

I'm trying to return a `char` array from memory and I just get some random value. I can't figure out what's wrong. This is my code:

stack.h:

```
struct node{
    char s[MAX_STRING_SIZE];
    struct node * next;
};

typedef struct {
    struct node * head;
} stack;
```

stack.c:

```
char * pop(stack * my_stack){
    if (my_stack->head == NULL){
        printf("Stack is empty.");
        exit(0);
    } else {
        struct node * tmp = my_stack->head;
        char * s = tmp->s;

        my_stack->head = my_stack->head->next;

        free(tmp);

        return s;
    }
}
```

main.c:

```
char * s2 = pop(&my_stack);
printf("%s\n", s2);
```

This prints just some random value to console. I checked and pop deletes node from memory correctly. How do I correctly return this string ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The line

```
free(tmp);
```

frees memory which includes the string you return.  (Once freed, memory may be reused at any point.  It may also become unreadable from your process in some cases.  Presumably you're seeing a "random value" because you're running a debug build in which the heap manager immediately sets freed memory to a different value.)

There are a few ways you could fix this, including

- change `pop` to return `node*`, leaving the caller to `free` the popped node
- return `void` from `pop`, printing the value of `s` inside `pop` before `tmp` is freed
- allocate memory inside `pop`, copying `tmp->s` into this then returning this newly allocated block (which the caller would have to free).  I don't recommend this; having a stack popping function which fails in low memory would be very odd...

Comment: I allocated space for a string in a function and copied head->s to this string and I returned it. It worked, however I'm wondering what happens to all this memory I allocate everytime I pop an element ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  The `node` being popped has its memory returned to the system for potential reuse by the call `free(tmp)`.  After this point, the contents of the memory may immediately change or may remain unchanged for a long time.  The only safe rule to follow is that the memory is no longer owned by you so you must not attempt to read it.  If this doesn't help, can you try restating which area(s) are unclear please?